# My words are all carried away

Tags: meaning

*I talk to the wind / My words are all carried away / I talk to the wind / The wind does not hear / The wind cannot hear.*

This is the second line of King Crimson's song I talk to the wind. I have the problems with understanding of the second verse ( *My words are all carried away*). I know the idiom "to be carried away" which means to be excited about something but this meaning does not fit to the the verse. I intuitively understand this verse as the expression of uselessness of talking to the wind but I'm not sure…

Comment: I think you understood well. He is so excited that his words are out of control.

Comment: @Khan: A person can get carried away (i.e. go "out of control) and then their words or actions may reflect their emotional state. But their words and actions do not themselves get carried away, in this sense.

Comment: TRomano, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking of "to get carried away".   Here, to be carried away means that the words are taken away by the wind, i.e. carried off on the wind, like fallen leaves perhaps, or the seeds of a plant that have become airborne.